# Calling python script from PowerPoint/VBA

Tags: python, vba, powerpoint

I'd like to be able to run Python scripts (that create slides and contents) from *PowerPoint*, just like an icon in an add-in. I saw that it's possible in Excel using a programm called [ExcelPython](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639887/Calling-Python-code-from-Excel-with-ExcelPython) and the Py scripts are called using VBA.

But for PowerPoint, any way ?

Many thanks

Comment: Must be a way -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284658/insert-images-to-powerpoint-slide-using-python-win32com-client

Answer (score 2):

As long as you can execute your script from the command line, it should be possible from PPT as well.  Here's an example of starting Notepad with a filename as a command line parameter:

```
Sub CallExternalProgram()
    Shell "Notepad.exe newfile.txt"
End Sub
```

You'd have to supply the full path to the executable if it's not on the path.

Comment: Something like the code below ?
'Sub CallExternalProgram()
    Shell "Python.exe script.py"
End Sub'

Comment: Yes, though if there are spaces in the path or filename, it gets a little trickier, so maybe:  Shell Chr$(34) & "programname.exe" & Chr$(34) & " " & Chr$(34) & "script name" & Chr$(34)

Comment: One other thing to be aware of ... Shell will fire it off but it won't wait for it to complete.  That can be a bit startling the first time you run into it.